# how does \includegraphics from the graphicx get the size of a .jpg image

Tags: graphics, metadata

Is there someplace where I can read about how `\includegrapics` uses the metadata that is stored with a JPG image?

I have carefully sized 80 images with Photoshop such that the Photoshop's ImageSize data shows the correct size in inches and a resolutions (300ppi) which calculates out to the same size in pixels. With `\includegraphics`, most of the images come out to be their specified size (in inches, and presumably in their underlying pixels) in the PDF file.  However, about a dozen of the images which seem to be specified the same way in Photoshop output to the PDF much bigger than they should be.  Is is possible that these non-working images were originally scanned at 600ppi (I've lost track of what happened during the scanning several years ago) rather than 300ppi and I resampled them with Photoshop to keep that same size in inches while reducing the resolution and thus the size in pixels?

When I look at the metadata with another image processing program (FastStone Image Viewer) it looks correct.  My goal is to avoid explicit specification of image width or whatever by sizing the images correctly so LaTeX output them correctly in their `\includegraphics` input mode.  Thus, I am looking for what other bit of metadata `\incloudegraphics` may be finding that gets the wrong result for me.  Thus my request for a pointer to how `\includegraphics` "does its thing."  I have a two line program (between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`) and two image files (with seemly correct metadata) which demonstrate my problem (unless I am missing something).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `pdftex` is (statically) linked to some libraries and I guess it relies on them to provide the correct information. The primitive `\pdfximage` is in charge of retrieving the information; the bounding box data can be examined with `\pdfximagebbox`.

Comment: I tried the following pattern for my images: \pdfximage{afile.jpg}
\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 1 % Returns lower-left x
\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 2 % Returns lower-left y
\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 3 % Returns upper-right x
\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 4 % Returns upper-right y
and get back four results of 0.0pt.  Is that supposed to work for a .jpg, or is a bounding box a .eps/.pdf concept?

Comment: Hmm, it seems that `\pdfimagebbox` is good only for PDF files; `pdftex.cfg` just says `\pdfximage{<file>}` and then `\setbox\@tempboxa=\hbox{\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}` in order to know the dimensions of the image.

Comment: I still have no understanding of the problem I posed in the question.  However, by converting the dozen or so JPEGs which \includegrahics didn't handle correctly to PNGs, things now work.  Perhaps this conversion eliminated whatever metadata was hanging around in the JPEG metadata and confusing \includegraphics.  I didn't try converting back from PNGs to JPEGs to see if that also worked.  I still think it would be nice to see documentation of how \includegraphics gets the size metadata from the various format images it handles from pdflatex.

Comment: You should look in the sources of `pdftex`, because `\includegraphics` just does what I showed earlier, so it just uses `\pdfximage` and makes a box.

Comment: @egreg There have been several changes to pdftex.def and others. Do you want to write an answer?