# How to vertically center image in table cell

Tags: tables, graphics

I am trying to place an image in the first column of a 4 column table. However the image is going over the top horizontal line. How can I set the image in the center of the cell so that the top horizontal line is properly displayed?

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$a_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$a_{2}$} \\
\hline
col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 \\
\hline
\includegraphics[height=.2in]{./Figures2/paths/abc.jpg} & text & text & text\\
\hline
\includegraphics[height=.2in]{./Figures2/paths/abc.jpg} & text & text & text\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The image:

[image]

and the output:

[image]

After making the image transparent:
[image]

Comment: If you get overprinting then the image is larger than tex thinks it is, which is not supposed to happen. which version of tex are you using? eg texlive 2014 pdflatex , or xetex or ...

Comment: you could try converting the jpg to png using an external tool such as imagemagic convert

Comment: note other people have reported problems with jpg image size http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171906/how-does-includegraphics-from-the-graphicx-get-the-size-of-a-jpg-image

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Transparent image has done the trick. but the images is still near the top horizontal line.

Comment: You can use `\raisebox` or (more easily) the `adjustbox` package which can add extra keys to `\includegraphics` to specify centre alignment, also use `\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}` to expand the table rows 9or whatever number works best)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `cellspace` package is done for that. It defines a minimal vertical distance between the contents of a cell and the cells above and below. All you have to do is prefix the column qualifier with the letter `S` ( or `C` if you've loaded `siunitx`).

To keep the other cells vertically centred, I defined a `\cincludegraphics` command.

I think this code produces what you want:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{4pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{4pt}

\newcommand\cincludegraphics[2][]{\raisebox{-0.3\height}{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| Sc |c | c | c |}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{$a_{1}$} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$a_{2}$} \\
  \hline
  col1 & col2 & col3 & col4 \\
  \hline
  \cincludegraphics[height=.2in]{abc.jpg} & text & text & text \\
  \hline
  \cincludegraphics[height=.2in]{abc.jpg} & text & text & text \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help :) Is there any way to used different settings for different column? I have used S for all columns. The image is now properly center. But the text in other columns are closer to the bottom horizontal line. Please check the output here: http://postimg.org/image/xcni5c1q1/

Comment: I see. It is enough to use S for the relevant columns. For the problem of text not being vertically centred, this is due to the `\includegraphics` command: usually, graphics file has a height, but no depth. I defined a `\cincludegraphics` command as a workaround. I hope it's OK now.

Comment: You're welcome. It's always a pleasure to help!

Comment: Just what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

After many years ...

With use of `adjustbox` (which load `graphicx` package too) and `tabularray` package for table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={*{4}{c}},
             row{1} ={mode=math},
             }
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    a_{1}
        &       &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    a_{2}   
                    &               \\
col1    & col2  & col3  & col4      \\
\includegraphics[height=0.2in, width=1in, valign=m]{example-image} 
        & text  &   \includegraphics[height=0.2in, width=1in, valign=m]{example-image}
                    &   text        \\
\includegraphics[height=0.2in, width=1in, valign=m]{example-image}
        & text  &   \includegraphics[height=0.2in, width=1in, valign=m]{example-image}
                    &   text        \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]