# How to make rows containing images equidistant with tabularray?

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, tabularray

Working with tabularray, I'm currently stuck trying to make rows that contain images equidistant from each other.

For instance, having this grid of images:

[image]

The images A, B, C are the ones that I would like to have the same separation between them.

I have tried forcing a certain `rowsep` between them and to [vertically center the images within the cell](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632779/226745), but without luck:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
            colspec = {ccc},
            rowsep = 1pt,
            cell{1}{1-2} = {r=3}{c},
        }
        \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image} & 
        \includegraphics[width=0.30\textwidth]{example-image} &
        \includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth, valign=m]{example-image-a} \\
        - & - & \includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth, valign=m]{example-image-b} \\
        - & - & \includegraphics[width=0.08\textwidth, valign=m]{example-image-c} 
    \end{tblr}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Example 5.2 https://github.com/AnMnv/eBook

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    \begin{tblr}{
            vspan=even,
            colspec = {ccc},
            rowsep = 1pt,
            cell{1}{1-2} = {r=3}{c},
        }
```

[image]