Vertically center text in table
How is it possible to vertically-center the text of the cells?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}



\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{ AAAAAAAA } \\
\hline \multicolumn{6}{|c|}{ BBBB} \\
\hline \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{CCCC} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ DDDD} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ RRRRRR } \\
\hline \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{PTTTT} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ HHHH } & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{ GGGG } \\
\hline Name & Ordre & $X(m)$ & $Y(m)$ & VVVVV & ZZZZZ \\
\hline 
20009 &  & 506 & 141 & cell & \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{Capture.jpeg} \\
\hline 
cell & & 406 & 370 & & \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{Capture.jpeg} \\
\hline 
cell & & 51 & 142 & Quadripode en fer & \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{Capture.jpeg} \\
\hline 
cell & & cell & 1419 & Mono & \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm]{Capture.jpeg} \\
\hline test & & &  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{cell}  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}               

\end{document} 

here is what I get


I don't know how to do it in my code

Thanks to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/632779/151808.
tabularray is not required, but I found it very useful.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularray}



\begin{document}
  \begin{tblr}{
      colspec = {*{6}{Q[c,m]}},
      stretch = 0,
      rowsep = 6pt,
      hlines, vlines
    }
    \SetCell[r=1,c=6]{} AAAAAAAA &&&& \\
    \SetCell[r=1,c=6]{} BBBB &&&&& \\
    \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} CCCC && \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} DDDD && \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} RRRRRR \\
    \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} PTTTT && \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} HHHH && \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} GGGG \\
    Name & Ordre & $X(m)$ & $Y(m)$ & VVVVV & ZZZZZ \\
    
    20009 &  & 506 & 141 & cell & {\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-a}} \\
     
    {cell\\ aze} & & 406 & 370 & & {\includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-a}} \\
     
    cell & & 51 & 142 & Quadripode en fer & \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-a} \\
     
    cell & & cell & 1419 & Mono & \includegraphics[width=2cm, height=2cm, valign=m]{example-image-a} \\
    test & & &  & \SetCell[r=1,c=2]{} cell & \\
  \end{tblr}
  
\end{document}



Thank you very much @NBur, you saved my day
